# Saas price table advice

Tags: usability, website-design

I am working on a plan /tier selection view for a Saas product.
We are offering a monthly subscription model as well as fixed term model.
So user can choose between recurring monthly payments or 1/3/6/12 month prepaid terms.

We are considering two options here:

1) Wizard like interface with several steps:

- Select Plan
- Select Recurring / Fixed
- If fixed - Term selection

2) Single screen with all options visible at once (see wireframe)
[image: Single screen option]

The wizard approach is not let to see all the prices (we offer discounts on long terms) and also seems unnatural and not cool :)

On the other hand - single screen is too heavy and can be somehow confusing...

What is your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have a SaaS business and we've found that too many pricing options gets complicated for us and for customers. Not necessarily tiers, but options. For instance you want to have 1/3/6/12 month payment options, and that's too much. That's why most companies offer monthly and yearly, and show them together with a clear discount (generally 10% or a month "free").

Your layout is fine, so long as it shows the differences between the tier options and at the bottom lists the price and price difference for the recurring bill times.

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with single screen but somewhat simplified.

This is based on [Smugmug's feature page](http://www.smugmug.com/features) which tells you the prices (and features) but the actual buying is on the other page. This mockup has purchase options on the same page.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6TEMN.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Prices are changed to monthly fees for easier comparison of the savings per plan.

You could also (if you haven't already) check these questions:

- [Price plan table with multiple payment options](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/16836/price-plan-table-with-multiple-payment-options)
- [Pricing page: single vs multiple call-to-action button with multiple plans (example inside)](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/53133/pricing-page-single-vs-multiple-call-to-action-button-with-multiple-plans-exam)

Comment: thank you for very interesting approach. Probably, I will go with it, but I have additional question. How should I handle changing plans for existing users? Should I use the same page? this one more fills like belong to landing page. What do you think?